# Time series with scala and spark. Rolling window

Tags: scala, apache-spark, time-series, window-functions

I'm trying to work on the following exercise using Scala and spark.

Given a file containing two columns: a time in seconds and a value

Example:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|     seconds         |     value        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          225        |         1,5      |
|          245        |         0,5      |
|          300        |         2,4      |
|          319        |         1,2      |
|          320        |         4,6      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

and given a value `V` to be used for the rolling window this output should be created:

Example with `V=20`

```
|--------------|---------|--------------------|----------------------|
|     seconds  |  value  |  num_row_in_window |sum_values_in_windows |
|--------------|---------|--------------------|----------------------|
|       225    |    1,5  |          1         |          1,5         |
|       245    |    0,5  |          2         |           2          |
|       300    |    2,4  |          1         |          2,4         |
|       319    |    1,2  |          2         |          3,6         |
|       320    |    4,6  |          3         |          8,2         |
|--------------|---------|--------------------|----------------------|
```

`num_row_in_window` is the number of rows contained in the current window and 
`sum_values_in_windows` is the sum of the values contained in the current window.

I've been trying with the sliding function or using the sql api but it's a bit unclear to me which is the best solution to tackle this problem considering that I'm a spark/scala novice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a perfect application for window-functions. By using `rangeBetween` you can set your sliding window to 20s. Note that in the example below no partitioning is specified (no `partitionBy`). Without a partitioning, this code will not scale:

```
import ss.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  (225, 1.5),
  (245, 0.5),
  (300, 2.4),
  (319, 1.2),
  (320, 4.6)
).toDF("seconds", "value")

val window = Window.orderBy($"seconds").rangeBetween(-20L, 0L) // add partitioning here

df
  .withColumn("num_row_in_window", sum(lit(1)).over(window))
  .withColumn("sum_values_in_window", sum($"value").over(window))
  .show()

+-------+-----+-----------------+--------------------+
|seconds|value|num_row_in_window|sum_values_in_window|
+-------+-----+-----------------+--------------------+
|    225|  1.5|                1|                 1.5|
|    245|  0.5|                2|                 2.0|
|    300|  2.4|                1|                 2.4|
|    319|  1.2|                2|                 3.6| 
|    320|  4.6|                3|                 8.2|
+-------+-----+-----------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: is there a way to take only the value of the current row in case there are duplicated values in the seconds column?
Let's say there are two row with seconds=300, the rangeBetween would consider them to be part of the same window. Is there a way to not go over, so to say, the current row? @raphael-roth

Comment: @user2697881 not sure what you mean, but I would remove duplicates before calculating the rolling sum.

Comment: How to remove the first row after calculating the rolling sum. In general, after I calculate the rolling sum for every N rows, how to remove the first N-1 rows?